# How can I apply CSS code from a server request to a react app?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a single React app that hosts a lot of customer websites and can be styled in a number of different ways. I'd like to allow my users to apply their own provided CSS code to their own website. Users wouldn't generally move directly between websites so just applying it at load time would be fine, however the React code needs to run in order to know which site is being used (the server knowns nothing about the URL containing the website name).

I saw this site which describes several ways to apply styles in React but none are helpful for my use case.
https://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-write-css-in-react/

Is my best option to ignore React and just use vanilla Javascript to create a `<style>` element and add it to the `<head>`?

Edit: The css data will come as a string from a GET request to the server which will return something like this:

```
{
  "name":"My Website",
  "currency":"EUR",
  "css": ".classone { display: none; } body { font-family: sans-serif; }"
  "defaultCountry": "FR"
}
```

Comment: Context seems important here. You'd want to at least show us how you intend to accept the CSS from the user.

Comment: I've done something that isn't React, but should work in React the same as I'm using it.  I allow a user to provide some limited custom CSS which I then store in my database on the server. Pages all include a normal style link element like `<link type="text/css" href="custom.css">` but "custom.css" isn't a file, it is a server endpoint (a Spring @Controller in Java in my case) that loads the css from the database and streams it out in response to the GET request for custom.css ... but as isherwood says, your context is important here.

Comment: @StephenP yes I did consider that but I'd still need to add the `<link>` to the code programatically because the React code needs to do some work before knowing which website the user is requesting. Definitely a good consideration though, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically adding user-supplied CSS to an already running React app is not really any different than letting a user switch themes. The core idea in both is to design your components in a way that allows dynamic styling.

There are a lot of approaches to theme management and integration in React apps. You would need a solution that doesn't involve pre-compilation of the CSS files.

One options that I've used several times is [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/). It is one of the css-in-jsx libraries, but it also has very good theme support and its underlying engine is built to take strings that appear to be CSS and apply them as styles to components. The only difference in your case is that the CSS would be coming from an external source during app-run time.

However, styled-components is mostly designed to apply styles to individual components not to manage global styles. That would mean that the individual components of your customer's sites would need to be aware of and consume whatever uploaded CSS was available.

If that isn't feasible, then you might want to take a look at styled-component's [createGlobalStyle](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) helper.

Something like this (partially borrowed from [How To Create Global Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366175/how-to-create-global-styles-with-styled-components-in-react-and-next-js-and-is-i) StackOverflow answer)

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

import {UserApp, getUserStyle} from "@/apps/User1";

const UserProvidedCss = createGlobalStyle`
    ${() => getUserStyle()}
`;

export default function AppContainer() {
  return (
    <>
      <UserProvidedCss />
      <UserApp />
    </>
  );
}
```

As long as you had a way to structure separation between user apps you could allow each user to provide both their own app and their own CSS.

You would probably move the `getUserStyle()` into a component itself so that the user's component would reload if/when the user uploaded new CSS, but the overall idea is the same.

Such a setup would be odd for React however. Also, `createGlobalStyle` only works for Web-rendered React Apps. It does not work out of the box with hybrid apps that make use of server-side rendering (like Next.js).